# How to call nested data values

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm very new to backbone.js and I'm trying to display the nested array values but all I get displayed is ojbect Object.

I know the data is returned because I can see it in the response (see below).

```
<span class="lbl"> <%= title %> <%= status %> <%= questions[0] %></span>
```

The above displays
Programming Draft `[object Object]`

I've also tried

```
<span class="lbl"> <%= title %> <%= status %> <%= questions.question %> </span>
```

But it returns 
Programming Draft

Response

```
{
    "title": "Programming",
    "category": "IT",
    "_id": "5269344db00754f370000012",
    "__v": 0,
    "status": "Draft",
    "questions": [
      {
        "_id": "5269344db00754f37000000e",
        "difficulty_level": "Medium",
        "question_type": "Pick One",
        "question": "How long is a piece of string?",
        "tags": [
          "General"
        ],
        "answer_options": [
          {
            "a_option": "Way too long!",
            "answer": "False"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Not long enough",
            "answer": "False"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "A Frayed Knot",
            "answer": "True"
          }
        ],
        "allow_dont_knows": false,
        "status": "Draft",
        "requires_approval": false
      },
      {
        "_id": "5269344db00754f37000000f",
        "difficulty_level": "Medium",
        "question_type": "Pick One",
        "question": "What is the nearest planet to earth?",
        "tags": [
          "Science",
          "Space"
        ],
        "answer_options": [
          {
            "a_option": "Mars",
            "answer": "False"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Venus",
            "answer": "True"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Jupiter",
            "answer": "False"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Neptune",
            "answer": "False"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Saturn",
            "answer": "False"
          }
        ],
        "allow_dont_knows": false,
        "status": "Draft",
        "requires_approval": false
      },
      {
        "_id": "5269344db00754f370000010",
        "difficulty_level": "Medium",
        "question_type": "Pick One",
        "question": "What is the largest planet?",
        "tags": [
          "Science",
          "Space"
        ],
        "answer_options": [
          {
            "a_option": "Mars",
            "answer": "False"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Venus",
            "answer": "False"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Jupiter",
            "answer": "True"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Neptune",
            "answer": "False"
          },
          {
            "a_option": "Saturn",
            "answer": "False"
          }
        ],
        "allow_dont_knows": false,
        "status": "Draft",
        "requires_approval": false
      }
    ],
    "requires_approval": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access to the index of the item in the array and after that you need to indicate the name of the property you want to show.

```
<span class="lbl"> <%= title %> <%= status %> <%= questions[0].question %></span>
```

If you want to show each question of questions you need to add a for and inside access to the questions with an index.

```
<% for(var i=0, len=questions.length; i<len; i++) { %>
<span class="lbl"> <%= title %> <%= status %> <%= questions[i].question %></span>
<% } %>
```